# Virtual Ticket selling

Tags: plugins

I'm hoping someone knows of a way to offer virtual tickets that can be assigned an access code that is emailed upon purchase, and that when is used, starts a 24 hour (or whatever time limit) to use the ticket or it expires.

I super hoping that some of the ticketing plugins or services can do this; like Eventbrite or Event Tickets or Fooevents... I have yet to find if they can do this.

Working in WP.

Any info on this is greatly appreciated!

Christine

Answer (score 0):

I use a paid plugin called License Manager for WooCommerce (found in Themeforest), but also looks like there is a [free version](https://wordpress.org/plugins/license-manager-for-woocommerce/).

It can send out random codes, preset imported codes, image based codes that you import, or codes with a prefix or suffix.  It does, however, require WooCommerce.

If you had say 20 access codes, you could import them and then sell them, emailed upon completed checkout.